# Change label and image opacity when radio button checked?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been struggling with this for about an hour now and I'm not sure what the best approach is. I have a radio button which has a label and an image. What I would like is for the radio button, label and image to be at 0.4 percent opacity initially and when the user checks a radio button, set the opacity to 1.0.

Here is what I have so far, I tried changing classes with JavaScript/jQuery but I would like to do this with pure CSS if possible.

My radio button HTML (note that this is sitting within a table):

```
<td class="answer">
    <!-- <div id="radio-<%= question.id %>" onclick="test('radio-grp-<%= question.id %>', 'outline-<%= question.id %>-r-<%= tmp %>','q-<%= question.id %>-r-<%= tmp %>')"> -->
    <div id="radio-<%= question.id %>">    
            <div class="radio-btn">  
            <!-- <div id="outline-<%= question.id %>-r-<%= tmp %>" class="radio-btn">   -->
            <input id="q-<%= question.id %>-r-<%= tmp %>" type="radio" name="radio-grp-<%= question.id %>" >
            <label for="q-<%= question.id %>-r-<%= tmp %>">
                <img src="/images/signal.png" class="radio-image">
                <p class="radio-heading"><%= question.choiceAnswer[tmp][0] %></p>
                <p class="radio-detail"><%= question.choiceAnswer[tmp][1] %></p>
            </label>
            </div>  
        </div> 
</td>
```

My CSS:

```
.radio-btn input[type="radio"], .radio-image, .radio-heading, .radio-detail {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
.radio-btn input[type="radio"]:checked {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

This gives me the desired effect when everything is unchecked, however, when you check a radio button, only the radio button itself is back to 1.0 opacity. How can I specify the other classes in the checked state? I tried `, .radio-image, .radio-heading,` but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try This CSS, Make use of sibling Selector(+), which selects the `label` and set its child classes opacity to 1.

Give this a Try

CSS

```
.radio-btn input[type="radio"]:checked + label .radio-image,
.radio-btn input[type="radio"]:checked + label .radio-heading,
.radio-btn input[type="radio"]:checked + label .radio-detail
{
  opacity:1.0;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/mhjjce23/4/)

Hope This Helps..